# Should I specialise in a single weapon or work on two?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

As you can unlock another raged weapon slot is it worth working on two weapons or specialising in one? I guess this is linked to how abundant karma is in the game, but currently I'm working on Pistol, which makes having the second weapon slot feel a little redundant.

So ideally, is putting points into two weapons a more sound strategy, or will single weapon specialisation yield better rewards further down the line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is better to increase the stats of only one weapon type, as you cannot grind for Karma. It is nearly impossible to max out body, quickness, dodge and you weapon of choice. Especially if it is a melee one, because you also need strength additionally.

You can always use your second slot for a different weapon of the same weapon type. Sometimes the cost of reloading is just too much and even if your secondary weapon is not as good as your first it will do the job.

You can try it yourself. There is a new user generated content map out where you can create a new character with as much Karma and money as you want. Then you can use the money to get all the items in the game that are available.

Just create a character with the same amount of Karma and try to fight with one weapon type versus two weapon type. You will see that you get better results with one weapon. At least this was the case for me.

Think of it that way: If you have 7 in pistols, 7 in shotguns and 6 in dodge then you have basically the same damage capabilities as someone who has 7 pistols and 9 in dodge, but the later will get hit way less.

Comment: This makes sense, however your strategy revolves around it costing you 1 AP to reload. Once you reach a certain level, reloading becomes free, which undermines this point. Are there any weapons of the same type which have sufficiently different attributes to warrant carrying two of the same weapon type?

Comment: Imo only pistols can be reloaded for free, so with other weapon types second weapon to can save realoading make sense there even for high karma character.

Answer (score 0):

Shotguns are great for clumped up groups of enemies, for doing ridiculous single AP damage, and for slowing the movement of fast MOBS, but if you advance the pistol tree as well you'll get much more flexibility and when your shotgun runs empty you never have to reload your handgun,

Answer (score -1):

A two weapon specialization is the best strategy. This way when you unlock better weapons you can always have that second channel. If you specialize in one, it may handicap your ability to complete levels easier down the line.

Comment: I agree, having now put a few points into Shotgun, I've found the combination of Pistol and Shotgun to be very useful and effective.

Comment: @DavidYell I'm happy I could help, upvoting the answer would make my day :)

Comment: I've accepted your answer. If you are wanting rep, you'll get more for an accepted answer than you will for an upvote.

Comment: @DavidYell you can do both if you like the answer.

Comment: @Blem Yes, I could, but I feel that accepting the answer is enough in this case.